# Switch order of differential and real operator in expression in Python

Tags: python, sympy

Let's say I want to simplify the terms

[[image: Differential of real(expression)]

where *u* and *v* are (sympy) complex variables. *u* and *w* are independent from each other and the above differentials should thereby be evaluated to zero. As my code currently stands, it will not set the above differentials to zero since it does not know how to evaluate re(*w*) and im(*w*) (see reason below). Is there a way to tell Python/Sympy to reverse the order of operation between the differential and re/im operator, i.e to evaluate them as:

[image: real(Differential of expression]

Since then Python can evaluate the differentials, and since they both are zero to begin with, it can set re(0) and im(0) to zero automatically.

I am basically looking for a solution to this where I don't have to decompose *u* and *w* into

[image: Decomposition]

with *u_1, u_2, w_1, w_2* real

**Initial attempt**: I noticed that one can use sympy.subs to swith the re operator to im operator by `[expression].subs({re: im})`. Maybe one could do something similiar with the differential and re/im operator to switch the order, but I do not know how to write the differential operator inside of `subs`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use `doit`:

```
In [3]: v, w = symbols('v, w')

In [4]: diff(re(w), v)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: Derivative(re(w), v)
Out[5]: 
d        
──(re(w))
dv       

In [6]: Derivative(re(w), v).doit()
Out[6]: 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes doit seems like a very simple fix. However, I noticed that it would only simplify the derivative if there were  no matching variables between the expression and the ones we are taking the differential with respect to, e.g it would not simplify 'd/dv (re(v))'  or  more importantly"d^2/(du*dv) (u*w*k), where u,v,w,k are all independent complex variables. The latter should be obviously be zero. These are the terms that really appear in my expression, I used more simple derivatives in my question since I did not think it would make any difference.

Comment: So do you know of a way to solve this with doit?

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question rather than using the comments here.

Comment: I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74639164/doit-in-python-not-simplifying-derivatives-when-re-im-operator-included)

Answer (score 0):

The `doit` is good since, otherwise, an unevaluated `Derivative(x, y)` will not evaluate to 0. But...if you want to do as requested, you can use a `replace` command to look for a derivative whose argument is `re` or `im` like this, using the `args` and `func` attributes of the expressions:

```py
>>> eq = Derivative(re(x),y)
>>> eq.replace(
...   lambda x: isinstance(x, Derivative) and isinstance(x.args[0], (re,im)),
...   lambda x: x.args[0].func(x.func(x.args[0].args[0], *x.args[1:])))
re(Derivative(x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, neat code! I wanted to use doit initially since I have 18 complex variables in my expression, and different combinations of their products, but I could not make it work with derivatives of products (see comment in @Oscar's answer, if you have a suggestion please let me know). So I will probably have to use Replace as you suggest if doit does not work out.

Comment: It would help if you give an input and an expected output that is not being obtained as desired.

Comment: Yes of course! As suggested by a user in the comments, I have posted a new question with these details  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74639164/doit-in-python-not-simplifying-derivatives-when-re-im-operator-included)