# Doit in Python not simplifying derivatives when re/im operator included

Tags: python, sympy

This is a continuation on my previous question [Switch order of differential and real operator in expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74610786/switch-order-of-differential-and-real-operator-in-expression-in-python/74612851?noredirect=1#comment131728718_74612851).

I would like to simplify the following derivatives in Python

[image: My_Differentials]

where u and v are independent (Sympy) complex variables. The derivatives and the re operator are commutative here, and hence by switching their order it automatically follows that their values are 1 and 0 respectively.

My code will not simplify the above expressions by itself (it will print them as are), and so I was advised in my previous question to use doit, i.e`[Differential].doit()`. However this only seems to simplify the expression if we are taking the differential with respect to a variable (say some complex variable k) which never appears in the function we are differentiating, i.e `doit` will simplify

[image: Will_not_simplify]

but not

[image: Will_simplify]

even though both are clearly zero. Note that there are no issues if the re operator is removed. Any suggestions on how to come around this problem with doit, or any other similar method?

Comment: Please include code in your questions to demonstrate what you have tried to do including all imports and defining all symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You have two complex variables:

```
In [1]: u, v = symbols('u, v')

In [2]: diff(re(u*v), u, v)
Out[2]: 
   2          
  ∂           
─────(re(u⋅v))
∂v ∂u
```

Here you just get an unevaluated `Derivative` back. That is SymPy's way of saying that it can't compute an expression for this derivative.

Now what should the derivative actually be?

You said "the derivatives and the re operator are commutative here" but that isn't true because the derivatives don't exist: the real part function `re` is not complex differentiable.

As for the other point:

```
In [3]: diff(re(u), v)
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: diff(re(u), v, v)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: diff(re(u), u, v)
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: diff(re(u), v, u)
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: diff(re(u), u, u)
Out[7]: 
  2       
 d        
───(re(u))
  2       
du
```

These are all zero as expected apart from the last one which is undefined because `re` is not complex differentiable:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789582/is-the-complex-function-fz-rez-differentiable